# How to split columns in windows Form listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code :

```
private void btnGetListProvince_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbRandomPoint.Clear();
            lvProvince.Clear();
            try
            {
                rtbRandomPoint.AppendText("\n" + " Successfully get all Province in Viet Nam");
                lvProvince.Columns.Add("id", 70);
                lvProvince.Columns.Add("name", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

                provinces = ProvinceController.getProvinceListByCountry();

                for (int i = 0; i <= provinces.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Province province = provinces[i];
                    lvProvince.Items.Add(province.Id);
                    lvProvince.Items.Add(province.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WarningHelper.ShowExeptionMessage(ex);
            }
        }
```

The results when running will produce results like the image below :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDGiz.png)

I want to sort by ID column with name column, as my result they are messy.

I tried below but it lost the column Name :

```
private void btnFilterProvince_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvResultCommune.Clear();
            rtbResult.Clear();
            try
            {
                rtbResult.AppendText("\n" + " Successfully get all Province in Viet Nam");
                lvResultCommune.Columns.Add("id", 70);
                lvResultCommune.Columns.Add("name", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

                provinces = ProvinceController.getProvinceListByCountry();

                for (int i = 0; i <= provinces.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Province province = provinces[i];
                    lvResultCommune.Items.Add(province.Id);
                    lvResultCommune.Items[i].SubItems.Add(province.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WarningHelper.ShowExeptionMessage(ex);
            }
        }
```

Anyone have any suggestions for me? thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `View` property to `Details`

```
lvResultCommune.View = View.Details;
```